# VMware mouse back/forward mouse buttons not working (Win7 Host, OS X Guest)

Tags: windows-7, macos, mouse, vmware-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Back / Forward mouse buttons do not work in VMWare Workstation 6.5 Guest OS](https://superuser.com/questions/35830/back-forward-mouse-buttons-do-not-work-in-vmware-workstation-6-5-guest-os)

I have a problem very similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/35830/back-forward-mouse-buttons-do-not-work-in-vmware-workstation-6-5-guest-os) but my host system is Win7 and my guest system is OS X 10.6. I already have usb.generic.allowHID = TRUE in my vmx file. I also tried steermouse. USB overdrive crashes for me after installation+restart at the window asking me to configure/buy/try. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I think all the buttons "work", but the 4th and 5th (back/forward) buttons are detected as the third button (middle click). When I click the 4th or 5th button in Firefox the auto-scroll action is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

> I either figured it out or found a work-around. This probably only
>   works for a laptop or a computer with two mouse input devices. What I
>   do is power on my virtual guest machine (OSX), connect my usb mouse, a
>   new device (a usb mouse) shows up in the status bar of vmware at the
>   bottom right. Right-click the new device, choose "Connect (disconnect
>   from host)". It then gives me an error saying the host needs the
>   device for input. Then I pull out my mouse, wait 2 seconds, and plug
>   it back in. VMWare will then automatically use the mouse for the guest
>   machine. You will not be able to use it for your host machine, so use
>   your laptop's touchpad for that if you need to access the host. Note:
>   you MUST choose "Connect (disconnect from host)" and get the error
>   first! If you don't do this, VMWare will not automatically connect the
>   mouse to the guest. I tried!
>
> By the way, I also have usb.generic.allowHID = "TRUE" and
>   mouse.vusb.enable = "TRUE" in my .VMX file as well as SteerMouse
>   installed on my Guest machine (OSX). Don't know if these things are
>   important or not.
>
> Hope this helps for people looking for a solution.